# Passing Roman numerals for getting output

Tags: javascript, decimal, roman-numerals

So I am almost through with the code for converting decimal to roman numerals for performing Arithmetic operations. Right now if I pass 100 + 200 = CCC which is correct that is 300. However, how do I tweak my code so that it accepts the following pattern -

**C + CC = CCC**

```
(function toRoman(num1, sign, num2) {
var r1 = '',
    r2 = '',
    decimals = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1],
    roman = ['M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I'];

    var translateRomanNumeral = function(num1) {
        for (var k = 0; k < num1.length; k++) {
            if (!(num1[k] in decimals)) {
            return null;
           }
        }
     }

    if (typeof num1 == 'string') {
        num1 = translateRomanNumeral(num1);
    }

   var translateRomanNumeral2 = function(num2) {
       for (var l = 0; l < num2.length; l++) {
          if (!(num2[l] in decimals)) {
          return null;
          }
        }
      }

  if (typeof num2 == 'string') {
     num2 = translateRomanNumeral2(num2);
  }     


for (var i = 0; i < decimals.length; i++) {
    while (num1 >= decimals[i]) {
      r1 += roman[i];
      num1 -= decimals[i];
      }
    }

for (var j = 0; j < decimals.length; j++) {
    while (num2 >= decimals[j]) {
      r2 += roman[j];
      num2 -= decimals[j];
     }
   }

switch (sign) {
    case "+": return r1 + r2;
    case "-": return r1 - r2;
    case "*": return r1 * r2;
    default: return r1 / r2;
   }
return r1, sign, r2;

})('C', '+', 'CC');
```

Comment: You need to write a function that parses Roman numerals into numbers.

Comment: @Barmar I am already doing it. However, how do I do it for the input? Instead of passing 100 and 200, how do I pass in the Roman numerals in the input instead.

Comment: `toRoman('C', '+', 'CC')`

Comment: Where are you already doing it? I don't see anything in your code that converts Roman numbers. It only goes the other way.

Comment: Correct. It gives me no output if I try to use toRoman('C', '+', 'CC') directly. I am confused as to how to integrate the solution to the given answer. As that other post just has a simple conversion and no Arithmetic operations with multiple inputs

Comment: `if (typeof num1 == 'string') { num1 = translateRomanNumeral(num1); }`

Comment: Do the same thing for `num2`, then the rest of the function is the same.